# Get position of cursor when highlight the text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I need to create a *Chrome Extension* which people can use to look up words. And I have found that I use double-click method like when I want to find meaning of a word I just double click and then the notification will appear. *(The image below is my Chrome Extension.)*

[image].

- However, I find it is difficult for user to find meaning of pharsal
  verb, collocation and sentence.
- **So come up with an idea that I can get the position of cursor when
  user select text and to the last letter of this text I get the
  position.**

[image]

- In addition, I also have found many other Chrome extensions support
  this feature and they are so great!. One of them is "Edge Translate". When I higlight a text and then I release the mouse it appears a little popup ball then I click to this ball it appears panel. This is their extension: *https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edge-translate/bocbaocobfecmglnmeaeppambideimao?hl=en*

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text selected you could use this function, then remove the dots, and other characters you are not interested in and split the selected text by spaces to get the last word. (also you don't need the cursor coordinates for it, so you could remove this piece. of the code)

```
  let hasSelection = false;
  function showCoordsForMouseUp(event) {
      const selection = window.getSelection().toString()
      hasSelection = selection.length;
      if (hasSelection) {
          const x = event.clientX;
          const y = event.clientY;
          const coords = `X coords: ${x} , Y coords: ${y}`;
          console.log(`${coords} - ${selection}`)
      } else {
          console.log('No text selected')
      }
  }

  document.onmouseup = showCoordsForMouseUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contribution, I have found the solution with onMouseUp Event.

```js
document.onmouseup = function F(e) {
  x = e.pageX;
  y = e.pageY;
  if (window.getSelection().toString() != "") {
    console.log("X: " + x + "Y: " + y);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  Flower, flowers.
</p>
```